# Why are files in /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume>/_data/ not visible from within a docker container?

Tags: docker

Learning about docker (on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTE (bionic)), and specifically about managing persistent data, I found [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume/).

Following the example over there, I tried to add some files to a volume, and then list them from within a container:

```
root@srv /v/l/machines# docker volume create hello
hello
root@srv /v/l/machines# docker run -d -v hello:/world busybox ls /world

Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
57c14dd66db0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7964ad52e396a6e045c39b5a44438424ac52e12e4d5a25d94895f2058cb863a0
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
d488dd535de01209ccc4f4bbf9a269d7932868ca41c9fe538d7a95fad66cefae
```

There is no data in the volume so the `ls` output is empty. This is OK.

```
root@srv /v/l/machines# docker volume inspect hello
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-01-14T14:57:47+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello/_data",
        "Name": "hello",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
root@srv /v/l/machines# date > /var/lib/docker/volumes/hello/_data/a.txt
root@srv /v/l/machines# date > /var/lib/docker/volumes/hello/_data/b.txt
root@srv /v/l/machines# docker run -d -v hello:/world busybox ls /world

ced5591203511f2f9a0194431ba8fca81df8442c38be993de454cadb1b93da09
root@srv /v/l/machines# docker run -d -v hello:/world busybox ls /world

7987ce187747016e81469cb1a150aa0a85ded58521fbc03f1a0f55e2e07358f0

root@srv /v/l/machines# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/hello/_data/
a.txt  b.txt
```

This part I do not understand. **I added some files to the place pointed out by `docker volume inspect` but they do not seem to be visible form within a docker container which mounted that volume. Why is it so?**

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: @jannis this is Ubuntu 18.04 LTE (bionic). I will update the question with the information

Comment: Interesting question, tagged it to follow the answers. I've searched docker's mans and was unable to find explicit explanation on `local` driver on how it manages data. My suggestion - folder is used only to flush the data, but the data itself may be stored in memory until being flushed, that's why modifications from outside container are not visible. But that's only a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container is running in detached mode, which is why you do not see any output.

Try running `docker logs <container-id>` and it should show the result of your `ls`-command.

Alternatively, you could omit the `-d` flag to run the container in foreground. This is useful particularly in cases when you just want to try things.

Documentation: [docker run – detached vs foreground](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground)